# Need entirely free SQL database for Mobile Application

Tags: gratis, android, ios, mobile, sql

I'm in the early stages of building a mobile app (starting with Android and then IOS). Upon opening the app I want user filters to be able to query real time into the remote database and load current state data. I want to use a SQL DB. I can't find anything for entirely free. And I'm not talking about very much data, maybe 500-1000 rows (~10 columns) across a couple tables. I do not have the knowledge or equipment to host my own server.

(Amazon RDS is only free for first 12 months)

Comment: The SQL database must be remote, right? Not stored locally on the mobile device?

Comment: By the way: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/are-hosting-recommendation-requests-on-topic

Comment: "`I want to use a SQL DB. I can't find anything for entirely free`" - what's wrong with SQLite, on the device itself? You can also use it on your server, as you can MySQL and its fork MariaDB.Did you look at any of those?

Comment: Another good choice is Firebird DB, though the Android version is still considered beta https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-3-0/ . It is *very* easy to install and maintain, and a minimal installation can consume less than 10 MB.